# HTML5 - Article Structure: Sections and Headers

Tags: html

I've found a lot of conflicting information on HTML5 best practices, and am wondering if my article structure is correct. In general, the pages on this site will consist of a header with nav, article, and footer.

Here's my basic structure:

```
<body>
    <header>Header content
        <nav>Navigation</nav>
    </header>
    <article>
        <header>
            <h1>Beans, beans</h1> <!--Main title for article-->
            <h2>Good for your heart?</h2> <!--Subtitle for article-->
        </header>
        <section>
            <header>
                <h3>Legume-based Flatulence</h3> <!--Section title-->
            </header>
            <p>Lorem ipsum beans beans beans.</p>
        </section>
        <section>
            <header>
                <h3>Gas and Good Feelings</h3>
            </header>
            <p>Correlation does not imply causation.</p>
            <footer> <!--Section footer for sources or...?-->
                Source: Phenomenological Farts, a Study in Siena
            </footer>
        </section>
        <section>
            <header>
                <h3>Beans for Every Meal?</h3>
            </header>
            <p>This is probably a terrible idea.</p>
        </section>
        <footer> <!--Article footer for additional downloads, etc-->
            <a href="#">Download this article!</a>
        </footer>
    </article>
    <footer>
        Footer content.
    </footer>
</body>
```

Does this make sense? Is it acceptable to use headers and footers within sections within articles?

Answer (score 2):

When you're unsure about what tags are allowed inside others, simply check the spec at [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/). Or run your code through a [validator](http://validator.w3.org/).
[The spec](http://www.w3.org/) states that [section](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/section.html), [header](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/header.html) and [article](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/article.html) tags can be used inside any container that allows [flow elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/common-models.html#common.elem.flow). So what you have so far is valid.

Comment: Thanks - I'm not so much concerned about what tags are allowed inside others (already familiar with that). I'm more concerned about following best practices. Perhaps "acceptable" was the wrong term for me to use in the question.

Comment: imo - I think if your html is structured in an easy to read way, and provides the layout you're after, then its all good!

Answer (score 0):

I was going to recomend `<hgroup>` for grouping headers, but it is no more: http://www.webmonkey.com/2013/04/w3c-drops-hgroup-tag-from-html5-spec/. Perhaps use `header` in its place. More info and suggestions from W3C: http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/common-idioms.html#sub-head

I would also then change your other `h3`s to `h2`s as they are the section header.

Finaly a `header` soley consisting of an `hx`  is kind of redundant.

More on [Headers](http://html5doctor.com/the-header-element/) and [Footers](http://html5doctor.com/the-footer-element-update/)